# How to validate record type as function input in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle 11g in Windows environment. I am not a thorough PL/SQL Developer. My situation is like this.

I am using a package, need to validate the logging in user. Not checking table column directly to do this.

```
create or replace package Configuration_pkg as

   TYPE user_rec IS RECORD
   (email     VARCHAR2(120),
    password  VARCHAR2(120)); 
  TYPE user_tab IS TABLE OF user_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  function Validate_logged_user (p_user_tab IN user_tab) RETURN VARCHAR2;
end Configuration_pkg;

create or replace package body Configuration_pkg as

  function Validate_logged_user (p_user_tab IN user_tab) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  Ismatching number;
begin
  select count(1)
    into Ismatching
    from CG_M_USERS
    where username = user_tab.email
    and password = user_tab.password;

  if Ismatching = 0 then
    return 'Invalid username / password';
  elsif Ismatching = 1 then
    return 'Login successful';
  end if;

end Validate_logged_user;

end Configuration_pkg;
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error(10,20): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "USER_TAB"."PASSWORD": invalid identifier
Error(10,29): PLS-00302: component 'PASSWORD' must be declared
```

I want to validate the user with the value passed with the record type, not directly checking username and password from table. Everyone's help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use parameter name - `p_user_tab` instead of  `user_tab`

Comment: Unrelated, but your `CG_M_USERS` table seems like a really bad security risk, holding clear text passwords.  If you can't get out of the business of validating users (i.e., by delegating authentication to an external service), storing a salted, secure hash would be far better.

Comment: Why do you need an array of records here?

Comment: Agreed to Jeff..you could had simply passed username and password as 2 variables to function. No need for a collection here.

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in your code.
1) You are using a Oracle reserve keyword 'PASSWORD'.
2) You are passing a collection to the function. So you need to run a loop to get the values of the collection.

See the revised complied code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Configuration_pkg
AS
   TYPE user_rec IS RECORD
   (
      email      VARCHAR2 (120),
      passwrd   VARCHAR2 (120)
   );

   TYPE user_tab IS TABLE OF user_rec  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   FUNCTION Validate_logged_user (p_user_tab IN user_tab)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

END Configuration_pkg;
----------------------------------------
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Configuration_pkg
IS
   FUNCTION Validate_logged_user (p_user_tab IN user_tab)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      Ismatching   NUMBER;
      msg1  varchar2(20):= 'Invalid username/passwrd';
      msg2  varchar2(20):= 'Login successful';
   BEGIN

    for r in 1..p_user_tab.count 
    loop

      SELECT COUNT (1)
        INTO Ismatching
        FROM CG_M_USERS
       WHERE username = p_user_tab(r).email 
       AND passwrd = p_user_tab(r).passwrd;

      IF Ismatching = 0
      THEN
         RETURN msg1;
      ELSIF Ismatching = 1
      THEN
         RETURN msg2;
      END IF;

    end loop;
   END Validate_logged_user;

END Configuration_pkg;
```